# Get User Input after keyboard inline keyboard selection Telegram Bot Python

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have an issue with my telegram bot. I wrote a bot in which the user needs to make a choice with an Inline Keyboard. If he selects 'Cerca un prodotto' the bot should wait for user input and print it. But if I start the bot then it prints the text 'FU' in `update.message.reply_text('HELLO FU', reply_markup=reply_markup_main)` row instead of printing user input. This is my code:

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler, CallbackQueryHandler, CallbackContext
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, ReplyKeyboardMarkup
from telegram import Update
import telegram

def start(update, context):
    kb_main = [
        [InlineKeyboardButton("Cerca le migliori offerte", callback_data='trovaofferte')],
        [InlineKeyboardButton("Cerca un prodotto", callback_data='cercaprod')]
    ]

    reply_markup_main = InlineKeyboardMarkup(kb_main)
    update.message.reply_text('HELLO FU', reply_markup=reply_markup_main)

def kb(update: Update, _: CallbackContext) -> None:
    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()

    #===> IF USER CHOICE IS 'cercaprod' THEN BOT SHOULD WAIT FOR USER INPUT<====
    if query.data == 'cercaprod':
        print(query.message.text)

def main():
   update= Updater('1655760090:AAFKyOR-i7wLW1zIAH9-air0EtqIDQJrCwk', use_context=True)
   disp=update.dispatcher

   disp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
   disp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, kb))
   update.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(kb))
   update.start_polling()
   update.idle()

if __name__=='__main__':
   main()
```

Answer (score 4):

A have a few remarks:

- You should revoke your bot token with @Botfather. Otherwise anyone could use it, because you posted it
- you use the callback `kb` in both a `MessageHandler` and a `CallbackQueryHandler`, but call `update.callback_query.answer()`. However, if the `update` is a message (in the `MessageHandler` case, `update.callback_query` will be `None` and you'll get an exception.

Now to the actual problem:

When the button is pressed, the only update you get is the `CallbackQuery` and `query.message` is the message that the button is attached to - in your case the message with text `HELLO FU`. If you want the user to enter some text *after* pressing the button, that will come in a new update. So you'd have to use a `MessageHandler` to catch that. I guess that's what you tried by setting up a `MessageHandler` with `kb` as callback, but as mentioned above that will only raise an error, which you currently won't see because you have no [logging](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/#logging) set up and no [error handler](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Exception-Handling).

For this kind of setup, I strongly recommend to use [`ConversationHandler`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.conversationhandler.html), which is perfect for setups where multiple user inputs are needed. There's also a neat example [here](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/telegram/ext/conversationhandler.py).